# Is there anyway to intercept Database calls in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to intercept all db call to get the query which is going to execute in DB.

After getting query i want to log query in DB.

Please share me your thoughts/intelligence.

Comment: Well, you can make all queries to db through your custom "proxy" class which will log these queries. Or just use SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: I never allow anyone to call a db with a query. Pass parameters to a stored procedure and control what happens.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Could u elaborate this "you can make all queries to db through your custom "proxy" class which will log these queries" more. Pls

Comment: @44444 Pretty straightforward. In most common words it could look like: create some class having method, say `QueryDB(SqlCommand cmd)`. This method should log command to be executed and then execute command. Then just use this method everywhere in your application instead of direct usage of SqlCommand. Thus all your commands will be "proxied" by this method.